# Should I approve edits to off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, scope

I was going through the Suggested Edits review queue (I received this privilege some days ago) when I stumbled upon [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5416548). The original question is clearly off-topic (OP is asking for a library) and also badly written.

However, someone decided to edit the question instead of voting to close it as off-topic.

I'm not sure whether I should approve the edit (because it *does* improve the readability of the question) or reject it (since, even after the edit, the question is still off-topic).

**Edit**:

It seems like the suggested edit has been approved in the mean time, but I'm still curious as to how I should handle cases like this in the future.

Comment: Frankly, that edit is bad and should have been rejected.

Comment: Just checked some of that user edits and it's a sad story overall... so few good edits in there.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau So few good reviewers, teaching editors how to *actually* edit, by rejecting their edits.

Comment: @J.Steen I'm well too aware despite having started reviewing edits just recently.

Comment: Coincidentally, I just reviewed another edit by the same user: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5416743. This time I decided to reject it.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Welcome to the party.

Comment: @Nic And then it was approved.

Comment: @J.Steen yes, unfortunately...

Comment: ugh, I hate those kind of edits that just reword things for no reason.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was discussed on MSE a few months ago: [Suggested edits for questions which should be closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228346/suggested-edits-for-questions-which-should-be-closed)

Quoting @RichardTingle

> Annoying answer: it depends.
>
> Somewhat more specific answer: it depends if the question could *ever* be salvaged and if this edit moves it in that direction.
>
> ## Editing spam, completely off topic questions etc
>
> If the question clearly shouldn't be here then there isn't much point editing it, we don't want people making perfectly grammatically correct spam. Equally if its just nothing to do with the site; such as "How do I learn sowing" on Stack Overflow then that is never going to be on topic. Reject in all these cases
>
> ## Editing closeworthy but potentially salvageable questions
>
> The [on hold] process is in place rather than an insta-delete process because some questions can be saved; e.g. questions which are unclear or too broad can be made clearer and narrower. If the edit *substantially* improves the post then accept, this leaves the OP will less to do to bring the question on topic. Use your judgement here, consider what is the best overall result.

In this case the question clearly shouldn't be here, so the edit should be rejected.

Answer (score 2):

If question is migrateable to some other SE it would be reasonable to approve edit as it is likely that question will end up in the correct site eventually and the better quality it gets there better chance it gets to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Should you approve edits to off-topic questions? [I think **yes**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237290/193139).

Should you have approved [this particular edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5416548)? I think no, it seems to be *too minor*.

Good edits to off-topic questions *can* be useful. Think of adding an important tag (→ getting the attention of relevant experts who might be able to salvage the question), or removing an unrelated tag (→ preventing that a closed off-topic question appears on wrong places when browsing the tag; not all closed questions get deleted).