# Should I edit an old, partially on-topic question to bring it on topic?

Tags: discussion

Here it is asked [Should I approve edits to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267093/should-i-approve-edits-to-off-topic-questions/267097#267097) and here is discussed [Suggested edits for questions which should be closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228346/suggested-edits-for-questions-which-should-be-closed) neither of which has made what to do in the following situation clear to me.

I've stumbled across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726380/any-good-net-ftp-free-library-to-upload-multiple-files?lq=1) which starts by asking for library suggestions (nowadays off topic) but then says "I am thinking of using following code [sic]". OP gets 2 answers: one is a poor quality set of search engine results, another is an answer which the answerer suggests might make OP's code work without having to use a library. The answer was accepted and upvoted.

So, am I allowed/encouraged/disencouraged/strictly-forbidden-under-the-pain-of-death to edit the question to remove the reference to library recommendations to bring in on topic (and at the same time freshen up the grammar etc.)? Such an edit is NOT in the "How to Edit" list, *does* change the meaning of the question which makes it strictly speaking "illegal", yet seems to me to be a "constructive edit" - saving a potentially off-topic question.

Does the presence of an answer to the off-topic part of the question have any impact what would be the "right thing to do" here?

Perhaps the question should be edited and the answer should be flagged? Perhaps the presence of an answer to the off-topic part of the question means the question should be flagged?

Comment: Generally you should not make edits which have the effect of making existing answers appear off-target - especially long after the fact and as a third party.  But perhaps you can do it in a way which preserves enough of the original intent to keep the existing answer valid (if still less than wonderful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can edit a question asking for a library recommendation in addition to an otherwise appropriate question to remove the library recommendation then by all means do so.  If the OP rolls it back don't get into an edit war, but in such a case you're turning a close-worthy question into an appropriate one while maintaining the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 1):

That question can definitely be saved with just a minor rephrasing.
[The non-marked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4726494/109702) should be down voted to oblivion* though - like you said it was once on topic but is now discouraged. Once it has gone negative it can be deleted, leaving just the good answer.

*... because there is no appropriate flag reason to get it into a review queue. It is an answer, but even in 2011 it wasn't a good quality one but that flag reason is not available due to the up votes.

Comment: Its gone by now.

Comment: -1 for recommending deletion of a well intentioned answer

Comment: @ChrisStratton you can downvote all you like but you are misguided. The *intention* of the answer doesn't matter. This is not a "you get an up vote for participation" site. We have definite guidelines for answers here, and that answer no longer meets them, and arguably didn't meet them when it was written 3.5 years ago. Not to mention that deletion is normally a community effort so it takes several people to agree.

Comment: Nope - you seem to be forgetting that the purpose of these sites is to provide a helpful resource.  Deleting potentially useful information is counter to that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton All due respect but you are incorrect with that statement. Links to outside material *without summarizing or excerpting* back to here are discouraged - answers that are just lists of links are shot on sight. The purpose of these sites is to collect factual and correct information, not links to outside resources, and not "potentially useful" information. I know some people find those collated links quite useful, but with few exceptions they are removed because long term they need maintenance.

Comment: IOW, links to outside resources should always be accompanied by an independant summary of the target, or standalone answer here on the site.

Comment: It's precisely the "I don't like the way that was presented, so it must be useless" mentality which you need to outgrow.  The real world doesn't work that way - links (while often not being ideal answers) are very useful clues to the presence of information which may be helpful.  It's simply not possible to make a viable *general argument* that erasing them is *more useful* than leaving them.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It is the decision that SE, as a site, has made.  It has come the the conclusion, over extensive discussion on the topic, that such posts, on the whole, cause a net harm as answers, and are below the minimum quality standard of the site.  You may not like it, but it is the standard of this community.  How you've managed to not be aware of this fact up to this point is baffling to me.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Sorry, you're wrong again. I've been around Meta for a very long time so I have a fair understanding of the current direction of the site, not to mention that I also moderate on another SE site (so I have to be pretty understanding with the whole "way information is presented" thing - I see all sorts). Bottom line is, links by themselves are poor answers, and lists of links just compound it.

Comment: Let's hope that in time you outgrow this counterproductive belief in deleting useful material.  As I said before, some time away from the site, in the real world of development, could be useful to supply the practical perspective that seems to go missing when one spends too much time here.