# What to do if OP requests tools or libraries to finish their task, but the task can be done without tools or library actually?

Tags: discussion, scope

Sometimes I can see OP is asking for tools or libraries to finish their tasks like this:

[What is the easiest way to convert xml to html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454948/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-convert-xml-to-html)

But at this question, converting xml to html can be done by Java itself, so my question is, if OP asks for tools or libraries, but they doesn't require them actually, is the question considered as on topic? Or can I edit to remove the tool requesting sentences to fit the rule?

Comment: _OP asks for tools or libraries_ -> CV as **Off-Topic**. _but they doesn't require them actually_ you can comment on the question stating the same, but that can again closed as **broad**. Chances are the question can be closed as **dupe**.

Comment: And for the linked question which is active _6 years ago_, I'd leave it as it is.

Comment: If you can edit the question to remove an off-topic request for something the asker doesn't actually need, whyever would you consider doing anything else?

Comment: @NathanTuggy is right, if a change as small as _"Is there any tool to foo the bar?"_ to _"How to foo the bar?"_ can make a question on-topic, by all means, **edit the question**. If any link-only answer popped up before the edit, flag and move on. It's also useful to precise why you did such an edit in the description. However, if such an edit would just make the question differently off-topic (_Too Broad_ instead of _Asking for off-site recommendation_ for example), then just flag / vote for closure.

Comment: Either close vote or edit and answer. Both is fine with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question can be salvaged to be on-topic and answerable, then by all means edit the question. It's kind of the point of putting questions in an 'on hold' state, to see if they can be salvaged before closing them completely.

Also see [Should I approve edits to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267093/should-i-approve-edits-to-off-topic-questions)